# Why have interactive controls in an MS-Access report?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm experimenting with Reports in MS-Access 2003 and I have to ask what value is there, if any, to adding interactive controls to a Report?  This includes Command Buttons, Checkboxes, etc that are made inactive once the Report is viewed in its proper Print Layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm opposed in general to the use of user interface controls on reports, but it actually is an advantage that you can save a form as a report. That's one reason you could end up with interactive controls on a report.

Arguably, one can also justify combo boxes and option groups, the first because it saves a join in the report's recordsource (which might cause complications or performance issues), and the second because it provides not just an indication of the stored value, but also what it means and what the other options are.

Check boxes I see no issue with at all. They are a good way of indicating Boolean values.

Command buttons I can't justify, but are likely supported simply for the compatibility issue that allows you to save a form as a report.

Comment: In access 2010 and I think in 2007 you can now launch a report in report view (as opposed to print preview). When you do this, then all of the buttons and controls events ARE active and do fire. In fact, this allows one to build rather interactive reports will drill down and active controls such as combo boxes to filter things. So the control click events etc. are active in later versions of Access.

I much concur that in previous versions, this ability is simply due to forms being used as sub-reports or being converted into a report.